# Assert arguments of stubbed methods with sinon

Tags: node.js, sinon, stubbing, sinon-chai

```
import ManagerDaoStub from '../salesforce/__test__/ManagerDaoStub';
import criticalMerchants from '../criticalMerchants';
describe('criticalMerchants Unit Tests', () => {
    before(() => {
        ManagerDaoStub.initStubs();    
    });
    after(() => {
        ManagerDaoStub.restoreStubs();
    });
    it('assert the arguments of stubbed method', (done)=>{
        let load = criticalMerchants.createCases(MERCHANT, DEVICE_ID, KEY, {});
        return done();
    });
})
```

This is the test file written in node `criticalMerchants.test.js`. The method i want to test which is `createCases` uses a method in `ManagerDao`, which has been stubbed in `ManagerDaoStub` as below.

```
import ManagerDao from '../ManagerDao';
class ManagerDaoStub {

    constructor() {
       this.sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create();
        }
    initStubs(sandbox) {
        this.sandbox = sandbox || this.sandbox;
        this.restoreStubs();
        this.initFindOpenCases();   
    }
    restoreStubs() {
        this.sandbox.restore();
    }
    initFindOpenCases() {
        let findOpenCases = this.sandbox.stub(ManagerDao, "findOpenCases");
        findOpenCases
            .withArgs(DEVICE_ID, KEY, match.func)
            .callsArgWith(2, new Error("Test error"));
   }
}
```

I want to assert whether this stubbed method `initFindOpenCases` was called with the right arguments (DEVICE_ID,KEY,null). I used 
`sinon.assert.calledWith(ManagerDaoStub.initFindOpenCases, DEVICE_ID, KEY, null)` and this gives the following error:

> AssertError: initFindOpenCases() is not stubbed.

Can someone suggest a proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

First off, if `ManagerDao.initFindOpenCases` is an instance method (I'm unsure since you haven't shared its definition), then you can't stub it on the constructor like you've done here:

```
let findOpenCases = this.sandbox.stub(ManagerDao, "findOpenCases")
```

You need to either create an instance first-- then stub it on that instance-- or stub it on the prototype itself like so:

```
let findOpenCases = this.sandbox.stub(ManagerDao.prototype, "findOpenCases");
```

Secondly, you're making the same mistake again in your assertion, combined with another:

```
sinon.assert.calledWith(ManagerDaoStub.initFindOpenCases, DEVICE_ID, KEY, null)
```

`ManagerDaoStub` is the constructor, and it does not *have* an `initFindOpenCases` property. Its *prototype* does, and thus its *instances* do as well. On top of that, `ManagerDaoStub.prototype.initFindOpenCases` is *still* not a stub. It's a method you're calling to *create* a stub, but it is not itself a stub. More plainly, you're getting `ManagerDao` mixed up with `ManagerDaoStub`.

Assuming you make example change above, you can make your assertion work like this:

```
sinon.assert.calledWith(ManagerDao.prototype.initFindOpenCases, DEVICE_ID, KEY, null)
```

*However*, this isn't all I would recommend changing. This latter mixup is arising largely because you're vastly over-complicating the setup code of your test. You don't need to make an entire class to stub one method of ManagerDao.

Instead, just replace your `before` and `after` calls with these:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    // Create the stub on the prototype.
    sinon.stub(ManagerDao.prototype, 'findOpenCases')
        .withArgs(DEVICE_ID, KEY, sinon.match.func)
        .callsArgWith(2, newError('Test Error'));
});
afterEach(() => {
    // As of sinon 5.0.0, the sinon object *is* a sandbox, so you can
    // easily restore every fake you've made like so:
    sinon.restore();
});
```

Aside from that, I recommend looking deeply into the difference between properties on a constructor and properties on its prototype. That knowledge will make stuff like this much easier for you. Best place to start is probably [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Obaject_prototypes).